# Image dimensions not showing in item info on second drive

Tags: finder

On my second drive image dimensions do not show. On my main drive they do.

Is there some way to enable that?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: The second drive is 'Mac OS Extended (Journaled)'. If i make a new folder on the drive and paste a pic in it works, but others it not. Yes, i have checked "Show Item Info" in View Options.

it shows item count and some file size info but not image dimensions

EDIT2: its just a folder tree on a drive that not show it... if i rename the tree they show, rename back and they stop showing. if i copy a file to a new dir or root it shows

how to change or reset what shows where? i tried adding and remiving from spotlight privacy window but

Comment: Need a little more information. What is the second drive formatted as? If the other drive is FAT32/NTFS, it might not support the metadata required for the files to show this info in the Get Info window.

Comment: FWIW, I have posted a similar question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/137468/force-os-x-finder-to-always-show-dimensions-of-images-in-sidebar I think it's a bug in OS X. It's still in Yosemite to this date(!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with thumbnails for movies, dimensions of images lots of times don't load until they are either opened, or left highlighted for a bit. I went through my images and found many didn't have dimensions either. After highlighting them for a minute or opening them with preview however, the dimensions showed. So chances are Finder doesn't open the file to find the dimensions until it needs to.

Comment: i can paste an image in root or new folder and shows dimensions right away