# Image dimensions infos on Lion Finder Columns view

Tags: finder

Since updating to Lion, none of my image show their dimensions in Finder column view. I tried highlighting a file for a while or opening it with Preview, [as suggested by this anser](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/image-dimensions-not-showing-in-item-info-on-second-drive#19256) without success. Here is a screenshot to visualize my problem :

[image]

**How can I see any file dimensions in Finder, like I did with Snow Leopard ?**

Comment: I received a reply from Apple engineering. As such, have modified my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this has to do with Spotlight. Finder's knowledge of additional file information is integrated with Spotlight, disabling it, or adding locations to the privacy  list will prevent Finder from reporting file information. This includes image dimensions.

[image]

If Finder is not reporting "More Info," make sure that directory is not blacklisted by Spotlight. In the screenshot above, anything found in the "Private" folder will show a "--" under the More Info section. This is by design.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in 10.7.2

Comment: @patrix Can you check images in your Downloads folder? I've been talking to Apple Support and through investigation, it looks like only images in the Downloads folder are affected. Can you verify this? Check an image in the downloads folder to see if it shows the additional info. If not, drag it to the Desktop and check it again. It should then be "fixed." I've checked numerous images outside of the Downloads folder and all work. Even the ones in the Download folder, once moved out of there. This is running the latest 10.7.2.

Comment: Indeed :-( Downloaded images still don't show dimension info in 10.7.2...

Comment: @patrix Okay. I've sent a follow up. Hopefully they now have enough info to crush this for the next release. Thanks for getting back to me :)

Comment: Wasn't fixed in 10.7.2 for me, but I checked only Applications for spotlight search results preferences, and excluded the Users folder in privacy. Changing that seems to do the trick. The "feature" is a bug IMHO

Comment: Apple assures me it is expected/designed behaviour; can't really argue with them. You could, however, file an enhancement request: http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html I think that would be a worthy submission.

Comment: I filed a radar://10315109

Comment: Still doesn't work for me on 10.7.3.  Experiencing same behavior as Ralph Mawyer below.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant for me. The times where image dimensions are shown are nothing but random to me. This bug, I'm sure it's a bug, is still in in OS X Yosemite, and has been since at least Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS 10.7.2
Spotlight - No Privacy entries
Display View = List

Initial loading of 100 images
Tabbing/selecting each image by mouse or cursor
Dimensions are not immediately displayed
Re-selection by mouse or tabbing may display the dimensions, but if you move off the image to another one and come back it's not there.
Basically very inconsistent and slow behavior.

If you Get Info on File it will not immediately display, but will ultimately.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this same issue with a brand new MacBook Pro + Lion.

Has nothing to do with the location of the image files, it happens this way with ALL of them in column view. However, if I switch to **Icon View**, hit <kbd>Cmd-J</kbd> and select "Show Item Info", the dimensions will display perfectly. When I switch back to column view, the dimensions are blank again.

Comment: I think you need to report this to Apple as this seems to be a bug with column view.