# Force OS X Finder to always show dimensions of images in sidebar

Tags: macos, finder

OS X Finder does sometimes, but not always, show the dimensions of an image selected in Finder, in the sidebar. Why? Is there a way to force it to always show the dimensions? It seems very arbitrary when it decides to show and not to show.

Note: this folder is on a local drive - the default Macintosh HD.

[image]

Comment: This is still buggy in current OS X (Yosemite 10.10.3). I should not that Finder mostly does not show the dimensions when the file is located on a network drive, or if local, resides in a folder which is part of some kind of "package" - I guess Finder assumes that file that are in packages are compressed or something and won't use resources to get such info to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to re-index the directories on your system by doing the following:

1. Go to `Apple > System Preferences > Spotlight` and chose the `Privacy` tab.
2. Drag a directory (or an entire volume) into the list, and confirm the action
3. Remove the directory (or volume) from the list via `-` it, which will trigger a re-index of the directory or volume.

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me in OS X 10.10.3

1. Open all the images in Preview.app at the same time; drag them all to Preview.app
2. With the Preview.app **Thumbnails Sidebar** (alt command 2) and the Preview.app **Inspector window** open (command i) use the arrow keys (up/down) to view through all of the images. Each one should be open long enough for you to see the images dimensions in the Inspector window.
3. Close Preview.app and now the **Finder Preview** sidebar will now show the image dimensions.